# Trouble installing gems with bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I'm new to Rails, following Michael Hartl's textbook. When I run `$ bundle install` I get the following error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 3.0.1) ruby depends on
      bundler (~> 1.0.0) ruby

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (1.7.6)

This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?
```

I then try `$ gem install bundler` which works fine:

```
Successfully installed bundler-1.7.6
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.7.6
1 gem installed
```

However, this doesn't solve the problem. I'm sensing this has something to do with version problems, but I'm not sure where to go with it...

Answer (score 1):

The following :

```
In Gemfile:
    rails (= 3.0.1) ruby depends on
      bundler (~> 1.0.0) ruby
```

means the version of bundler required is **greater than or equal to** 1.0.0 but strictly **less than** 1.1.0. Rails 3 is depending on an old version of bundler. At this point of time, you should try out Rails 4 instead :)

You may read up more about the "version syntax" in http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#pessimistic_version_constraint

Answer (score 0):

As @user3927334 has already stated the error you got is due to a version conflict between `bundler` and `rails`.

Most likely you have run `rails new my_app` with an outdated version of the rails gem.

```
gem install rails -v 4.2.0.beta4
```

Can be used to install a particular version of Rails. see [Installing Rails](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning#sec-installing_rails). 
You should then remove your old app and [rerun the app generator](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning#sec-the_hello_application):

```
rails _4.2.0.beta4_ new hello_app
```

If you indent to develop on your local machine I would recommend installing [RVM (Ruby Version Manager)](http://www.rvm.io) (as did previous versions of MH's *Ruby on Rails Tutorial*.)

It allows you to effortlessly switch between different versions of ruby and different sets of gems.

Comment: You can also update apps - but if you haven't yet done any work on the app just starting fresh with `rails new` is a lot easier. 
I have no idea why Michael Hartl is recommending that users start out on a beta instead of the latest stable branch.